# Difference between threads in Go and C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, go, locking, mutex

I have this thread safe queue (implemented in Go and C++) where I am spawning more than 100K threads to push data into a shared queue. On my laptop I have 8 cores and 16 logical processors with 16GB of RAM.

I wrote the same program on Go and C++ both. The program works fine with huge number of thread in Go on my personal machine but when I execute the program using C++ the program crashes and I get segmentation fault. I understood that its because I have 8 cores but I am spawning huge number of threads. But what I don't understand is how is Go handling this situation and why is C++ not configured to handle the situation in the same way?

How does Go differ from C++ from handling the threads internally?

The below code in Go works perfectly with 100K or above threads. However C++ is not even able to handles 5K threads.

**Go**

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
    "sync"
)

type ConcurrentQueue struct {
    queue []int32
    lock  sync.Mutex
}

func (q *ConcurrentQueue) Enqueue(item int32) {
    q.lock.Lock()
    defer q.lock.Unlock()
    q.queue = append(q.queue, item)
}

func (q *ConcurrentQueue) Dequeue() int32 {
    q.lock.Lock()
    defer q.lock.Unlock()

    if len(q.queue) == 0 {
        panic("removing from an empty queue")
    }
    item := q.queue[0]
    q.queue = q.queue[1:]
    return item
}

func (q *ConcurrentQueue) Size() int {
    q.lock.Lock()
    defer q.lock.Unlock()
    return len(q.queue)
}

const NUM_THREADS int = 100000

func main() {
    queue := &ConcurrentQueue{
        queue: make([]int32, 0),
    }

    var wgE sync.WaitGroup
    var wgD sync.WaitGroup

    fmt.Println("size before enqueue:", queue.Size())
    for i := 0; i < NUM_THREADS; i++ {
        wgE.Add(1)
        go func() {
            queue.Enqueue(rand.Int31())
            wgE.Done()
        }()
    }

    wgE.Wait()
    fmt.Println("size after enqueue:", queue.Size())

    for i := 0; i < NUM_THREADS; i++ {
        wgD.Add(1)
        go func() {
            queue.Dequeue()
            wgD.Done()
        }()
    }

    wgD.Wait()

    fmt.Println("size after dequeue:", queue.Size())
}
```

**Output:**

```
size before enqueue: 0
size after enqueue: 100000
size after dequeue: 0
```

The below code in C++ gives segmentation fault with 100K threads

**C++**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>

class ThreadSafeQueue
{
    private:
    std::queue<int> q;
    std::mutex qMutex;  
    std::condition_variable m_cond;
    public:
    ThreadSafeQueue() { }
    ThreadSafeQueue(const ThreadSafeQueue &) = delete ;
    ThreadSafeQueue& operator=(const ThreadSafeQueue &) = delete ;
    
    void Enqueue(int val);
    void Dequeue();
    size_t Size();
};

void ThreadSafeQueue::Enqueue(int val)
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(qMutex);
    q.push(val);
}

void ThreadSafeQueue::Dequeue()
{   
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(qMutex);

    m_cond.wait(lock, [this] {  return !q.empty(); }); 
    
    q.pop();
}

size_t ThreadSafeQueue::Size()
{
    return q.size();
}

void UpdateQueue(ThreadSafeQueue &qObj, int val)
{
    qObj.Enqueue(val);
}
void DeleteQueue(ThreadSafeQueue &qObj)
{
    qObj.Dequeue();
}

int main()
{
    int N;
    ThreadSafeQueue qObj;
    std::cout<<"How many values do you want to insert"<<std::endl;
    std::cin>>N;
    std::cout<<"Before inserting size of queue is "<<qObj.Size()<<std::endl;

    
    std::vector<std::thread> threads;
    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        threads.push_back(std::thread(UpdateQueue, std::ref(qObj), rand()));
    }

    for (auto& th : threads) th.join();
    threads.clear();
        
    std::cout<<"After inserting size of queue is "<<qObj.Size() <<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"Dequeuing using threads"<<std::endl;
    
    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        threads.push_back(std::thread(DeleteQueue, std::ref(qObj)));
    }
    for (auto& th : threads) th.join();
    std::cout<<"After dequeing size of queue is "<<qObj.Size()<<std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Your class is _named_ `ThreadSafeQueue`, but I don't see anything in there that makes it actually thread-safe.

Comment: oh sorry, pasted wrong code

Comment: @NathanPierson please check now

Comment: I think **Go** uses green threads (it's own threading abstraction), and C++ uses system threads.  Your 100k threads probably exhausts the available system threads, and *definitely* vastly exceeds the available logical cores.

Comment: Handling that many threads (in C++) is useless anything above std::hardware_concurrency is not going to speed up anything.

Comment: Yes Pepjin, I know that but its about the internal working of these 2 threads handling which I am more interested to know here

Comment: Ok, I can't help you with that. I only know about OS/system/C++ threads. I just know that when I have to switch from one language to another I don't take anything for granted and expect languages to have different philosphies (memory managment, lifetime of objects, value/reference semantics)... and now I learned threading might be one of those too :)

Comment: _"I am spawning more than 100K threads"_ - You should probably use a thread-pool instead.

Comment: The Go version uses not "threads" but "goroutines" which are _much_ more lightweight than threads (your Go code might just use 5 threads for all these goroutines).

Answer (score 9):

Goroutines are not the same as OS threads. Threads in C++ are actually OS threads. Answer can be very complex, but in short:

1. Go has its own runtime
2. Go can run multiple goroutines on one OS thread, it's managed by Go scheduler.
3. Go scheduler is work-stealing. You can find more details here: [Scheduling In Go : Part II - Go Scheduler](https://www.ardanlabs.com/blog/2018/08/scheduling-in-go-part2.html)
4. Goroutines is lightweight. They has only several kB stacks (2-8kB, depends on Go version and it's also dynamic: can be increased/decreased by Go). OS thread size usually several MB.
5. Only three registers involved (saved/restored) in switching Goroutine: Program Counter, Stack Pointer and DX. This is why it can be switched very fast comparing to OS threads and why you can spawn more goroutines than OS threads.

Answer (score 4):

> I don't understand is how is Go handling this situation

In Golang there's a layer, a runtime scheduler, between the actual system threads and your code. This scheduler keeps a thread pool of actual OS threads which it uses to execute your threaded code.

> why is Cpp not configured to handle the situation in the same way?

Because C++ threads are OS threads. You'll have to create a thread pool if you need it - or use [Coroutines](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/coroutines), [`std::async`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async) or [*Execution Polices*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/execution).

Comment: I haven't done profiling yet, but do you think there will be performance difference between the two? Would `Go` be faster for same task being multithreaded with 100K threads and C++ doing the same with max cores number of threads?

Comment: @HimanshuPoddar I'm expecting code that is written in a good way in C++ to be approximately as fast as Go when it comes to using the thread pool. Then, how the actual code executing in the threads is written matters a lot too. The built-in thread pool in C++ can be accessed with Execution Policies for example and with careful avoidance of false sharing (and making it lock free) it will be _very_ effective. The thing in C++ is that you are closer to hardware and can optimize it if needed - but it's also easy to make it ineffective, so care and profiling is a must.

Comment: @HimanshuPoddar -- Whether it is `C`, Go, C++, Python, or any other language, in the end they will use the same threading and synchronization primitives that the OS provides.  There isn't anything magical that `Go` is doing that C++ or any other language couldn't achieve.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie it depends on the effort you put in the code, GO threads are a mix of coroutines and threads which is crucial for IO bound tasks which GO is made for, yes you can write that in any other language, but if you are writing a server in a day, you better not waste it trying to get C++ threads and coroutines running together without crashes, yet if you have the time to write good C++ code to use them then this code will be faster than GO.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, that is not entirely accurate. When goroutines communicate using channels, the Go runtime knows which goroutine(s) to wake up. The OS does not provide a mechanism similar to channels.

Comment: @BurakSerdar Whatever Go uses, it's implemented on top of what the OS provides, so Paul is correct.

Comment: @TedLyngmo, of course. However, what Go provides is a language feature on top of what the OS provides. Sure, you can implement the same thing in any other language, but that would be with an additional library.

Comment: @BurakSerdar That's almost what Paul said. _"With" an additional library_ isn't needed though. I think that the fundamental parts needed are already in the C++ standard library.

Answer (score 1):

It's important to understand that [Concurrency is not parallelism](https://go.dev/blog/waza-talk). With concurrency, you can have separate logical tasks being executed in their own little world. But that doesn't mean they are running at the same time. With parallelism, these tasks are actually executing on different cores are the same moment in time.

In Go, goroutines express concurrency, not parallelism. In C++, threads express parallelism (which, in turn, express concurrency also). So when you asked "Difference between threads in Go and C++" it was actually the wrong question. The right question would have been "Difference between goroutines in Go and threads in C++".

Note that I was careful not to say "threads in Go," and that is important. In Go, *goroutines are not (necessarily) threads*. The Go runtime decides somehow weather or not to put goroutines in their own OS threads.

It's also true that goroutines are much "lighter" than the OS threads you'll find in C++ and other languages. What does that really mean to us as programmers?

No matter what language you use, OS threads don't just run forever without any interruption. There is a limit to how many threads can be running at once - that limit is the number of cores on your CPU. (We'll not get in to physical vs virtual cores here, it doesn't matter). But if there are more threads than cores, then the CPU must switch between them. This "context switch," as it'
s sometimes called, is *extremely* expensive relative to other operations. Every bit of state including the contents of the stack and the stack pointer, the instruction pointer and the cached code and data, and all the CPU registers must be saved out somewhere else - often, that ends up being RAM. And then the thread that it being resumed has to have it's entire state swapped back in. None of this is cheap, and for this reason blindly adding more OS threads to your application will not speed things up the way you might expect.

Go avoids all of that by using goroutines instead of threads. Very little state accompanies a goroutine if it isn't running as an OS thread. It's perfectly fine to create hundreds or thousands of goroutines in your application. It might not (or might) make your program faster, but it does at the very least give the go runtime an opportunity to put some goroutines in threads. In C++ however, you have to be pretty careful about what you try to parallelize. I used to say that the hardest thing a C++ applications programmer will ever do is correct multithreaded programming. That may not be the case any more, but it's still way more to think about than in Go with goroutines.